# Modular Discriminant and Pentagonal Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, number-theory, modular-forms, theta-functions

I am asked to show $$(2\pi)^{-12}\Delta(\tau) = q \cdot \Big (\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} (-1)^n \cdot q^{(3n^2+n)/2} \Big)^{24}$$ where $\Delta:\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{C}$ is the modular discriminant, $q=e^{2\pi i \tau}$.

My approach: Call the RHS $\vartheta(\tau)$. I've shown $\vartheta$ converges normally on $\mathbb{H}$. Now, $\Delta$ is a (holomorphic) cusp form of weight $12$ on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Since the vector space of such cusp forms is one-dimensional, if we show $\vartheta$ is a cusp form then we know $\delta = \alpha \vartheta$ for some constant $\alpha$. Then examining the Fourier expansion one can show $\alpha = (2\pi)^{12}$.

To show $\vartheta \in S_k$ we must check for any $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ that $\vartheta(\gamma \tau) = (c\tau+d)^{12}\vartheta(\tau)$, where $\gamma$ is the Mobius transform induced by the matrix. For this its enough to verify on the generators, which give transformations $\tau \to \tau + 1$, $\tau \to -1/\tau$. The first transformation is easy, but I can't figure out how to prove $\vartheta(-1/\tau) = \tau^{12} \vartheta(\tau)$.

I did a similar problem following the exact same procedure. It was to show $(2\pi)^{-12}\Delta(\tau) = 2^{-8}(\vartheta_1\vartheta_2\vartheta_3(\tau))^8$ for similar looking functions $\vartheta_j$. I was able to recognize these functions as theta functions and manipulate the theta transformation formula. In this problem, I'm failing to get theta transformation to work. Does anyone have any ideas? It should also be noted that we have been discussing vector valued theta functions recently on quadratic lattices, so maybe this is a necessary tool. Again, I can't find a way to apply these ideas though.

Another approach to the problem is using my previous exercise: note $\vartheta_1 = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}q^{n^2/2}$, $\vartheta_2 = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}(-1)^n \cdot q^{n^2/2}$, $\vartheta_3 = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}q^{(n+1/2)^2/2}$. Maybe one can quickly do the problem by the Cauchy product formula, but I'm bad at manipulating these messy sums.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is [your definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) of the LHS ?

Comment: $27G_4(\tau)^3 - 120G_6(\tau)^2$. I also know the Fourier expansion. I don't think this will be too helpful though. All I'm really using about it is that its a cusp form of weight $12$ and I'm looking at its Fourier coefficients.

Comment: smells like poisson summation

Comment: [later in this chapter we show that $\Delta(\tau) = (2\pi)^{12} \eta(\tau)^{24}$](https://books.google.fr/books?id=bDEMCAAAQBAJ&pg=PR2&lpg=PR2&dq=Modular+Functions+and+Dirichlet+Series+in+Number+Theory&source=bl&ots=sgVxsxSMAr&sig=w_dWh2qkEuqcg4PZ1UBZH-hFCLE&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-toyurLfLAhUob5oKHTDACkcQ6AEIQTAF#v=onepage&q=Modular%20Functions%20and%20Dirichlet%20Series%20in%20Number%20Theory&f=false)

Comment: and a full but older version [Apostol, Modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Apostol%20T.M.%20Modular%20functions%20and%20Dirichlet%20series%20in%20number%20theory%20(Springer,1990)(600dpi)(T)(216s)_MT_.pdf) (p. 57)

Comment: If anyone is curious...mathematica showed me how to do this with the Cauchy-product

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough "street cred" yet to post a comment, so I'm posting it as a solution.
 Invoke 
Euler's identity (i.e. Euler's Pentagonal Number Theorem)
$$\prod_{m\in \mathbb{N}} (1-q^m) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} (-1)^n \cdot q^{(3n^2+n)/2}$$
Also consult Theorem 6 on page 95 of Serre's "A Course in Arithmetic". A relatively short (shorter than Apostol's) proof due to Hurwitz is given based on an "elementary" modular forms approach rather than the longer more naturally motivated elliptic function approach.